# How to override post-code.js which is in vendor/module-ui?

Tags: javascript, overrides, magento-core

For testing purpose, we have modified the core file **post-code.js** which is in the path `/vendor/Magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element` and see it's working fine. So we have decided to override the file **post-code.js**.

For overriding, we have followed the below steps:

1. Created and copied the files on

> app/design/frontend/[VendorName]/[theme]/module-ui/web/js/form/element

2. Run the below commands

   ```
   php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   php bin/magento setup:di:compile
   php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
   ```

But it's not working as expected.

Could anyone please tell me how to override the "post-code.js"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this,

You must rename your **module-ui** to **Magento_Ui**

Copy the file from below path

> vendor/magento/module-ui/view/base/web/js/form/element/post-code.js

to

> app/design/frontend/{Vendor}/{theme-name}/Magento_Ui/web/js/form/element/post-code.js

then run the below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain why we need to change the module name from module-ui to Magento_Ui?

Comment: It is your module name will reside in registration.php inside module-ui module, that should be placed there

Answer (score 1):

**Rename module** name

```
 module-ui
```

to

```
 Magento_Ui
```

Comment: Thanks for the information. It works perfectly.